# Error TS2497: Module '...' resolves to a non-module entity and cannot be imported using this construct

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings, definitelytyped

Given this declaration file `promise-retry/index.d.ts`, which follows TypeScript's official [module-function.d.ts](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-function-d-ts.html) format:

**Edit:** *pasted the wrong code segment for this previously (which is still visible below)*:

```
export = promiseRetry;

declare function promiseRetry(options: Partial<PromiseRetry.NodeRetryOptions>, fn: (retry: PromiseRetry.RetryFn, attempt: number) => Promise<any>): Promise<any>;
declare function promiseRetry(fn: (retry: PromiseRetry.RetryFn, attempt: number) => Promise<any>, options ?: Partial<PromiseRetry.NodeRetryOptions>): Promise<any>;

declare namespace PromiseRetry {
    export interface NodeRetryOptions {
        forever: boolean;
        unref: boolean;
        retries: number;
        factor: number;
        minTimeout: number;
        maxTimeout: number;
        randomize: number | false;
    }

    export type RetryFn = (err: any) => never;
}
```

I find I cannot import `NodeRetryOptions` nor `RetryFn` via this syntax:

```
import {NodeRetryOptions, RetryFn} from "promise-retry";

let options: NodeRetryOptions = { forever: false };
let retryFn: RetryFn = (err:any)=>{throw "Nobody responds on StackOverflow"};
```

... as it throws the compile error: `error TS2497: Module '"promise-retry"' resolves to a non-module entity and cannot be imported using this construct.`

I also tried another syntax:

```
declare module "promise-retry" {
    export = promiseRetry;

    function promiseRetry(options: Partial<PromiseRetry.NodeRetryOptions>, fn: (retry: PromiseRetry.RetryFn, attempt: number) => Promise<any>): Promise<any>;
    function promiseRetry(fn: (retry: PromiseRetry.RetryFn, attempt: number) => Promise<any>, options ?: Partial<PromiseRetry.NodeRetryOptions>): Promise<any>;

    namespace PromiseRetry {
        export interface NodeRetryOptions {
            forever: boolean;
            unref: boolean;
            retries: number;
            factor: number;
            minTimeout: number;
            maxTimeout: number;
            randomize: number | false;
        }

        export type RetryFn = (err: any) => never;
    }
}
```

But the imports (in a different style) failed too:

```
import * as PromiseRetry from "promise-retry";

let options: PromiseRetry.NodeRetryOptions = { forever: false };
let retryFn: PromiseRetry.RetryFn = (err:any)=>{throw "Nobody responds on StackOverflow"};
```

... throwing the very same compiler error.

I've read everything I can find (including the related links here), and I can't get it working. In the words of Trump, "Nobody knew TypeScript imports could be so complicated."

Answer (score 3):

The [example you linked to](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-function-d-ts.html) has an important note in its comments:

```
/*~ Note that ES6 modules cannot directly export callable functions.
 *~ This file should be imported using the CommonJS-style:
 *~   import x = require('someLibrary');
 *~
 *~ Refer to the documentation to understand common
 *~ workarounds for this limitation of ES6 modules.
 */
```

What you probably want is the following:

```
export = PromiseRetry;

declare function PromiseRetry(options: Partial<PromiseRetry.NodeRetryOptions>, fn: (retry: PromiseRetry.RetryFn, attempt: number) => Promise<any>): Promise<any>;
declare function PromiseRetry(fn: (retry: PromiseRetry.RetryFn, attempt: number) => Promise<any>, options ?: Partial<PromiseRetry.NodeRetryOptions>): Promise<any>;

declare namespace PromiseRetry {
    export interface NodeRetryOptions {
        forever: boolean;
        unref?: boolean;
        retries?: number;
        factor?: number;
        minTimeout?: number; // milliseconds
        maxTimeout?: number; // milliseconds|(Number.)Infinity, which is itself of number type.
        randomize?: number | false;
    }

    export type RetryFn = (err: any) => never;
}
```

Note the capitalized `PromiseRetry` function to match the namespace. Then, to import, use the following line:

```
import PromiseRetry = require('promise-retry');
```

Usages must then be prefixed by the namespace as such:

```
let options: PromiseRetry.NodeRetryOptions = { forever: false };
let retryFn: PromiseRetry.RetryFn = (err:any) => {throw "Sometimes people respond on StackOverflow"};
```

---

As a side note, it seems that most packages are leaning against using namespaces to attach types as namespace children of function declarations. Another alternative that would allow you to use a different name for the function and the namespace would be the following:

```
export declare function promiseRetry(options: Partial<PromiseRetry.NodeRetryOptions>, fn: (retry: PromiseRetry.RetryFn, attempt: number) => Promise<any>): Promise<any>;
export declare function promiseRetry(fn: (retry: PromiseRetry.RetryFn, attempt: number) => Promise<any>, options ?: Partial<PromiseRetry.NodeRetryOptions>): Promise<any>;

declare namespace PromiseRetry {
    export interface NodeRetryOptions {
        forever: boolean;
        unref?: boolean;
        retries?: number;
        factor?: number;
        minTimeout?: number; // milliseconds
        maxTimeout?: number; // milliseconds|(Number.)Infinity, which is itself of number type.
        randomize?: number | false;
    }

    export type RetryFn = (err: any) => never;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. Your first option, with the suggested `import PromiseRetry = require("promise-retry");`, works for `PromiseRetry()` invocation, but throws *"cannot find namespace 'PromiseRetry'"* for the use of `PromiseRetry.NodeRetryOptions`. The second option works for `promiseRetry()` invocation, but again throws the same error. Adding `export` before `declare namespace PromiseRetry` had no effect on this error. What do you think I should do?